# Wordpress: display parent page of a custom post type and its sibling pages

Tags: wordpress, loops, menu, custom-post-type

I have the current page/post structure:

```
|-- Level 1 page
|---- Level 2 page
|---- Level 2 page
|---- Level 2 page
|------ Custom post type
```

Which would breadcrumb like this `Level 1 page > Level 2 page > Custom post type`

Is it possible to list the parent Level 2 page of the custom post, with a class of `current` and it's sibling Level 2 pages on the custom post template itself?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible

**To get page ids**

```
$current_level_two_page = get_pages(array('parent' => wp_get_post_parent_id()));
$all_level_two_pages = get_pages(array('parent' => $current_level_two_page));
```

**To get page names**

```
$pageNamesArray = [];
foreach ($all_level_two_pages as $pageId) {
  $pageNamesArray[$pageId] = get_the_title($pageId);
}
```

I can not test it but it should work.

For more details see [get_pages](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages) and [wp_get_post_parent_id](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_parent_id) and [get_the_title](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title).

Comment: Thanks for the response. This isn't returning anything on the front-end. Not sure how you display the data using the loop you described.

Comment: Well this is just loop to get names of pages. Of course it does not display anything.

Comment: If you want to display you can add `echo get_the_title($pageId);` inside `foreach` loop